# Dealing with PHP timeouts in Cron when PHP is in safe mode

Tags: php, cron, timeout

I have a PHP script running every hour or so. The script does a long process which is expected to be more than 2 hours. But my PHP is timing out every 60 seconds. I have used `set_time_limit(0);` but this is not allowed in safe mode i guess. So could you guys please tell me how to have infinite execution time without really changing the safe mode settings ?

Comment: What `phpinfo();` for your console script says?

Comment: What kind of a process is it?

Comment: what do i have to look there ?

Comment: @pekka: it is just creating pdfs and sending mails and some DB operations aswell..

Comment: safe mode is a bad idea and has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0

Comment: @Dagon: thanks for that info!! i will get my server team to update it!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the cron tab using php -n [path_to_your_script]

flag 'n' tells php to ignore the php.ini file settings.

Comment: so if i ignored php.ini setting will the time out business goes off ??

Comment: You will have to still do set_time_limit(0);